# Cross-Domain Session sharing is not working Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, login, customer-account, session, customer-session

I have 2 stores set up in two different domain names in one Magento Installation. I have enabled the `SID on Frontend` to share the session between the two stores using SID as an Url parameter. But it seems to be not working in any case. The login and cart session are still not able to share.

Is it due to any configuration regarding the server or in Magento we are missing some customization. I tried changing the `session.use_trans_sid` inside `php.ini` files. Then also it seems to be not working.

I am observing that the SID is in the Url but it not taking the session id instead it is creating a new session id. So please look into this and get back to me ASAP on this.

Comment: Any solution about sharing cart between stores?

Comment: No not till now.